# Removing first bit

Tags: c++, python

Is there an efficient way to remove the first bit of a number in C++ / Python, assuming you don't know how large the number is or its datatype?

I know in Python I can do it by getting the bin(n), truncating the string by 1, and then recasting it to an int, but I am curious if there is a more "mathematical" way to do this.

e.g. say the number is 6, which is 110 in binary. Chop the first bit and it becomes 10, or 2.

Comment: what's the "first bit"? most significant? least significant? If you know nothing about the size of the number or it's format, you'll probably trash the number completely. e.g. remove the most sig fig of a signed number and you've simply removed the sign bit. how do you handle an 8bit number v.s. a 16bit number? if it's 16bit and you remove bit 7,b ecause you thought it was an 8bit number, now you've trashed the value completely.

Comment: I don't know what most/least significant means but I added an example. I assume leftmost bit of value 1 is "most" significant, rightmost bit of value 1 is "least" significant

Comment: In C++, you might consider the [bit shift operations](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Companion/cxx_crib/shift.html).

Comment: How did you get 10 from 6? What bit was changed?

Comment: @cm2 -- bit shifting (and bit operations in general) works in python too for integers

Comment: @mgilson good to know -- I never do these sorts of operations... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a bit twiddling hack to remove a bit at a time until only the uppermost is left:

```
def upper_bit(x):
    while x & (x - 1):
        x &= x - 1
    return x
```

Now you can use that as a mask:

```
def mask_off(x, mask):
    return x & ~mask

>>> mask_off(6, upper_bit(6))
2
```

Note that this only works for positive numbers, because of the boundless nature of Python ints.

Comment: Isn't that the **lowest** bit?

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum, you're *removing* the highest bit to leave the lowest bit(s). That's what the problem was asking for.

Comment: Sorry - missed the while - yes that is the same as my answer

Answer (score 6):

looking at `110` (6 decimal)

The Most Significant bit is `100` (4 decimal)   *// -- Note that this is always a power of 2*

Create a mask: one less than the MSB is `011` (3 decimal)

Mask off the highest bit using bitwise-and: `110 & 011` = `10` (2 decimal)

*Calculating the MSB (Most Significant Bit) has been handled here and elsewhere quite often*

Comment: @catscradle -- Yeah, I just realized that (which is why I deleted my comment)

Comment: @catscradle that is the MSB ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718453/extract-n-most-significant-non-zero-bits-from-int-in-c-without-loops )

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could create a loop in which you would double some variable (say x) in each iteration and then check whether this variable is greater than your number. If it is, divide it by two and subtract from your number. For example, if your number is 11:

-first iteration: x=1<11, so continue

-second iteration: x =2<11, so continue

-third iteration: x=4<11, so continue

-fourth iteration: x=8<11, so continue

-fifth iteration: x=16>11, so divide x by two: x=8. Then subtract 8 from your number and get answer:

11-8=3.

Answer (score 2):

If you using a C compiler that supports [`__builtin_clz`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html), and you limit yourself to the type that `__builtin_clz` supports, you can do:

```
unsigned int chopWithBuiltin(unsigned int x) {
  //get number of leading redundant sign bits,
  //which is one less than the position of the MSB
  int msb_idx = __builtin_clz(x);
  //now make a mask that is all the bits below the MSB
  int mask = UINT_MAX >> (msb_idx+1);
  return x & mask;
}
```

This uses `__builtin_clz` which hopefully maps to something fast in assembly instead of a loop to detect the MSB.

For negative numbers you can build something similar with `__builtin_clrsb` but it gets complicated.

Answer (score 2):

First find the length of the binary number by log2(n) logarithm in base 2 of n

```
n = 6
l = int(log(n, 2)) + 1
```

As your number is 6 which is `110` in binary find the MSB `100` (4 in decimal).

```
mask = 2**(l-1) #msb will always be 2^(length-1)
```

Now simply use XOR operator to remove the MSB

```
res = n^mask
```

Code in one line would be

```
n = 2**int(log(n,2)) ^ n
```

Comment: Slightly more efficient, and removing the import would be `n = n^(1<<n.bit_length()-1)`

Comment: This actually solves the problem with large values of n.